# How to transform simple index dataframe to multi-index dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

considering this DataFrame, I don't know how to have a multi index DataFrame using Pandas :

[to see the DataFrame i'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6FYn.png)

My goal is to have "industry" as my multi index so like each "industry" have multiple row being each articles.

I've checked many other stackoverflow answers but i don't see how to transform a simple index Dataframe to a multi index one.

Any help would be welcome.

Thank you,

Comment: do you simply want to `set_index('industry')`? The wanted output is unclear and you should provide a **minimal text input**

Comment: Hi, kind of but i would like for 1 row index let's say "health care news" with multiple rows referring to "health care news".    When i do  set_index('industry') it has multiple line containing "health care news" as index i would like to have 1 "health care" index i dont know if that's clear

Comment: as said above, provide first a minimal input and output example as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the current numeric index you can try with

```
df.set_index(['industry', df.index], inplace=True)
```

If you want a new index you can use df.set_index(['industry', 'URL article'], inplace=True)
df.set_index(['industry', 'URL'], inplace=True)

This will not necessarily sort the index and may look "ugly".
[image: Before oder index]

To fix it you can sort the incidence with sort_index.

```
df.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

[image: After order index]

The final result of the code would be.

```
df.set_index(['industry', df.index], inplace=True)
df.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

> NOTE: The values used in the data frame are examples and do not match your photo.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df = df.set_index(["industry", "URL article"])
```